# Installshield - how to get the error thrown by the batch file to be displayed by the installer as a popup

Tags: batch-file, installshield

I am currently working on creating installer. I have a batch file which checks the tasklist to see if the task is running. If the task is running - I want to pause the installer and give the user the option to retry or close. User will either manually shut down the task and hit retry or close the installer.

I am not sure how to link the batch files error response with the installshield.

Is it possible to do this activity using the batch file alone and not involve the installscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  The .BAT file runs out of process and has no way of communicating back to InstallShield.

With InstallScript you can query WMI (Win32_Process) and drive the UI in a much more robust manner.